# Datacenter Reviews

Tags: colocation, datacenter

Anyone know of site that has a good amount of datacenter reviews?  I have looked at datacentertalk.com and webhostingstuff.com , but I didn't find much on those sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea for a community blog/website... :)

Maybe this can be fleshed out a little.

What factors would you grade a datacentre on?

Standard of customer service; quality of NOC staff; NOC staff availability (not just 9-5); availability of build room; price; etc...

Comment: I totally agree with your answer. What I typically find though is sites like that start out honest enough with good datacenter reviews, but then are soon overrun by advertisements for the 'big guys', drowning out the little guys who are just as capable on price, availability, etc; but do not have the "marketing arm" as the  others. You never know when a review is "honest", a planted review or a paid piece.

Comment: @Dave: sure, and what about putting something critical in about a datacentre you have a long-term relationship with? Most admins would probably not say anything unless it was anonymous. However, that kind of setup could be a good conduit between honest (but meek) admins and account managers. I dunno...

Answer (score 1):

For UK/Some European data centres data hop have [good summaries](http://www.datahop.net/datacentres/) containing some info that is not readily available elsewhere although obviously biased toward the ability to cable/put in transit hops.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datacenterknowledge.com have some good articles, news etc not user really reviews as such though

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a site like that is: I don't trust Joe Average to 'know' data centers as well as I do.  I also hugely distrust data center sales people.  I had one tell me that they were 'practically Tier 4!'  Yet I found many disqualifications to Tier 2 status on the tour.

Some of those that buy data centers (or data center space) don't really know what makes a DC.  Not to mention that we all have different qualification for a 'good' data center.  It depends on what you value.  Do you highly value technical remote hands?  Do you highly value the robust power infrastructure?  Do you highly value a robust cooling infrastructure?

For me, I want a really robust DC and external remote hands.  If the remote hands don't live up to my expectations, I can swap those out over the term.